# Jquery Insert element into a div, by cursor position

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="Texting" contenteditable="true">11111111111111111111111111111</h1>

<button id="BTN">AddText</button>
<script>

$('#BTN').click(function(){
   var str="<h1>GERLS GRUP SEX</h1>"; //h2 Element add to h1 id="Texting"

   //code
});
</script>
```

The task of inserting an element, indicating the cursor in h1, does not matter at least div, so that when the button is pressed at the specified cursor position in the `id = "Texting"` element `<g1> GERLS GRUP SEX </ h1>`
the species will be

```
<h1 id = "Texting" contenteditable = "true"> 11111111 <h1> GERLS GRUP SEX </ h1> 111111111111111111111 </ h1>
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something like that

```
$('#BTN').click(function(){
    var str="GERLS GRUP SEX";
    var htmlText = $("#Texting").html()
    var position = document.getSelection().anchorOffset;
    var result =  htmlText.slice(0, position) + str + htmlText.slice(position);
    console.log(result); 
    $("#Texting").html(result);
});
```

Comment: thanks work, this example is suitable for the editor))